If the integral of all real analytic functions vanish, does the measure vanish?
Suppose that $\mu$ is a (finite, signed, Borel) measure on $\mathbb R$ such that
$$\int d\mu(x) f(x) = 0$$
for all real analytic functions $f$. Is $\mu = 0$?
*I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I could not find the answer on my searches.
Context: This question emerged when I was attempting to prove the following. Let $h$ be any real analytic function, $X$ a self-adjoint operator and $A$ a collection of operators. Suppose that a relation $\mathfrak{J}[h,X;A] = 0$ can be established using explicitly the analyticity of $h$ (i.e., by expanding $h(X)$ in its Taylor series). Does it automatically extend to any other real measurable functions $f$, for a certain class of relations $\mathfrak{J}$? That is, $\mathfrak{J}[f,X;A] = 0$? (In this context, I would be interested in the case where $\mu$ is an operator-valued measure, taking values in bounded operators on a Hilbert space.)

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Of course $\mu$ is a signed measure, correct?

Yes. But more useful to my context, I would also be interested in the case where it is an operator-valued measure (taking values in bounded operators on a Hilbert space).

If $\mu$ has unbounded support, there are real analytic functions that are not in $L^1(\mu)$.  How do you interpret $\int d\mu(x) f(x) = 0$ in this case?

Indeed. I will add that $\mu$ is finite. In the context, $\mu$ takes values in bounded operators.

Are you assuming that every analytic $f$ is integrable with respect to $|\mu|$?

Yes, we can assume that.

Yes, this is true. Indeed, consider $A = \text{span}\{P(x)e^{-\alpha x^2}: P(x) \text{ is a polynomial, }\alpha > 0\}$. It is easy to check $A$ consists of analytic functions and is a subalgebra of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. $A$ vanishes nowhere. Indeed, $e^{-x^2}$ already vanishes nowhere. Moreover, $A$ separates points. Indeed, $e^{-x^2}$ and $xe^{-x^2}$ already separate points. Thus, by Stone-Weierstrass, $A$ is uniform norm dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. As $\mu$ is a finite measure and $\int f \, d\mu = 0$ for all $f \in A$, we conclude that $\int f \, d\mu = 0$ for all $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$. Thus, $\mu = 0$ by Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem.

Thanks for the answer. In the last step, when invoking RMK representation theorem, it seems that you need to assume that $\mu$ is regular, no? It says on Wikipedia that any Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is regular -- would this also be true for measures that are differences between two probability measures? If so, that could work for me, as I am interested in the case where the measure is the difference between two projection-valued measures.

@RodrigoAndradeESilva By definition, a signed measure $\mu$ is called regular if the positive measure $|\mu|$ is regular. When $\mu$ is finite, so is $|\mu|$. As you mentioned, any finite positive Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is regular. Combining the above, we obtain that $\mu$ is regular.

Thanks. I was able to prove my main theorem using your argument, so I will give you proper credit for this lemma.

@RodrigoAndradeESilva Consider accepting the answer if you find it satisfactory.
